# Using Entity Framework, how do I specify a sort on a navagation property?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have two tables: [Category], [Item]. They are connected by a join table: [CategoryAndItem]. It has two primary key fields: [CategoryKey], [ItemKey]. Foreign keys exist appropriately and Entity has no problem pulling this in and creating the correct navigation properties that connect the entity objects.

Basically each category can have multiple items, and items can be in multiple categories. The problem is that the order of items is specified per category, so that a particular item might be third in one category but fifth in another.

In the past, I have added a [Sequence] field to the join table and modified the stored procedure to handle it. But since Entity is replacing my stored procedures, I need to figure out how to make Entity handle the sequence.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The sequence is specific to the join per category. Because of this the sequence can't be a property of item. Item should not be aware of the sequence, even category shouldn't care about the sequence. It's the join that needs the info. I am hoping for a solution that lets me set the sequence on adding the items, then when I get a category and say category.items, they will be ordered by the same sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EntityCollection`s are unordered. You can read about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx). The workaround, when you need an ordered list, is to project onto a POCO presentation model or DTO:

```
var q = from c in Context.Categories
        select new CategoryPresentation
        {
            Key = c.Key,
            Items = from ci in c.CategoryAndItems
                    orderby ci.SequenceNo
                    select new ItemPresentation
                    {
                        Key = ci.Item.Key,
                        // etc.
                    },
             // etc.
        };
```

Comment: The sequence can't be on the item.

Comment: OK. If you put it in the join table then you no longer have a many to many. Instead you have a one to many and a many to one. I'll rewrite the query for that.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but it seems that this is the best solution atm.

Answer (score 0):

First option: use a stored procedure.  You can still use stored procedures with the Entity Framework, and [EF4 makes this easier than the original EF3 implementation did.](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/)

Second option: handle it manually.  Will you know at insert-time what Sequence order the CategoryAndItem record should get? If so, it could be as simple as setting that Entity's Sequence property to `1 + (From item as CategoryAndItem in model.CategoryAndItem select item.Sequence where item.Category = ... ).Max()`. (VB code, sorry :)).

Comment: How would I go about creating a sequence property for the join?